# how to replace a link name text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following markup to render a link :-

```
<a id="forum0-NewPostLink" class="ms-textXLarge ms-heroCommandLink" title="add new discussion" href="/Lists/erwerwerwerew/NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2F%2FSitePages%2FHome%2Easpx">
<span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20">
<img class="ms-list-addnew-img20" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23">
</span>
<span>new discussion</span>
</a>
```

now i want to replace the "new discussion" to be "new item". so can anyone adivce how i can do so using CSS or javascript ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are multiple links? And you want all to be replaced with the same? And you have jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you can do it like this with plain javascript, but this isn't a good aproach over all..

```
var a = document.getElementById('forum0-NewPostLink');
var b = a.getElementsByTagName('span');
var arr = [].slice.call(b);
arr.pop().innerHTML = 'new Item';
```

Comment: can you adivce why it is not a good approach ? also can i achieve this using pure CSS ...

Comment: Well, I've edited the answer a little bit, making it a little more failure approve, but it would be better if you would give the span an ID for example. If your html changes and you handle it like one of the answeres (including me) suggested, you will have to change all your code again. @johnG

Comment: i got your point ,, but can i achive the same using pure CSS.. and is using pure css a preferred approach over using javascript ?

Comment: Frankly I don't know a css approach to this, and I don't think there is one, but I'm more familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery can use:

```
$('#forum0-NewPostLink span:last').text('My new text');
```

if this needs to be more dynamic you will need to provide more details

CSS approach:

```css
#forum0-NewPostLink span:last-of-type {
    display:none
}
#forum0-NewPostLink:first-of-type:after{
    display:block;
    content:'New text'
}
```

<kbd>**[CSS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/28sukfqy/1)**</kbd>

Comment: only in stylesheet , not inline. Could hide the last span child and use `:after` pseudo selector and `content` property

Comment: but generally speaking should i always try to hide things using CSS instead of using javascript ?

Comment: @johnG not as simple to manipulate dynamically using css. I just added a css alternative

Comment: @charlietfl would you recommend using the css approach? Is it dynamic in any way? Please see the comments below my answer for why I'm asking.

Comment: @michael css isn't my strength for things like this however there wouldn't be any way to modify the css dynamically without using script. Such as add/modify a style tag but that's more work than changing the element text IMO

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, that was my thought, too. Thank you for clarification!

Comment: @michael so you mean pure css class will not be able to achieve this ,, and i need to use JavaScript or jquery ? is this correct ?

Comment: well, I don't really understand your use case, so it's hard to say, but I would use javascript for it, or just change the html if the change should be persistent

Comment: you really haven't identified what your needs are. I've shown 2 ways but if this needs to be changed after page load would need to use script to do it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its always second span under "a"

```
  $("#forum0-NewPostLink span:nth-child(2)").text('new text');
```